# how can I use elisp to print dependencies of a code?

Tags: emacs, dependency-management, transpiler, cedet

I am trying to print the dependencies associated with a code, such as definitions related to functions or variables in a statement using Emacs, however I am not finding the functions necessary to do it. I have already been able to parse the code, now I just need the printing part, for which I have been looking into the srecode package without success.

It will be a necessary step to translate Java code into C or C++

Comment: Please narrow your question to a single, specific question, providing the info necessary for understanding that question. Your specific question could perhaps be a restatement of this in more concrete terms (and as a question): *"I am not finding what I can use to print the definition(s) related to a statement."*

Answer (score 0):

What "code"? In what programming language? There are packages for different programming languages that could help. You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

to use emacs at this point perharps was a bad idea. I searched for code slicing and found some tools here: [slicers](https://github.com/topics/program-slicing). For the translation part I may use code from cogre-srecode.el from the cogre package of cedet and for it the manual of srecode is better